# My React Component state is continuously return null object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I trying to build a weather app for my training and I have a issues.

I got a Type Error whatever I do. what I intended to do is get a json data from weathermap api and then

show some strings but I couldn't.

here is main content from My app

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';



class Content extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: this.props.weather.main,
        };
    }



    render() {


    return (
        <View style={styles.content}>
            <Text style={styles.city}>City Name</Text>
    <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Weather {this.state.data}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Description</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Temperature Celsius</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Pressure</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Humidity</Text>        
        </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    content: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems:'center'
    },
    city: {
        fontSize: 50,
        padding: 20
    },
    itemsize: {
        fontSize: 30,
        padding: 5
    }
})

export default Content;
```

and this is my upper component which is trying to get data and pass down.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Content from './Content';
import GetWeather  from './GetWeather';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._getData.bind(this);
        this._getData();
        this.state = {
            data: null,
        };

    }

    _getData = () => {
        GetWeather.getWeather().then( json => {
            console.log(json);
            this.setState({data: json});

        }); 

    };
    render() {

        return (
            <Content weather={this.state.data}/>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

and last one is code that I wrote to get api data from openweathermap

```
function getLocation(lat, long) {
    return `${API_STEM}lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${APP_ID}`;

}
function getWeather() {
    return fetch(getLocation(LATTITUDE,LONGGITUDE))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => { 
        return { main: responseJson.weather[0].main};})
    .catch(err =>console.log(err));
}

export default {getWeather: getWeather};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parent component, state never gets data and always remains null. When we want to fetch data from an API, we should use a react lifecycle method called [componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). So in your parent component, you should either call your _getdata function in componentDidMount or fetch your data in the lifecycle method, like below code which is a better way in my opinion. Also, never initially set your state to null. set it to an empty object.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Content from './Content';
import GetWeather  from './GetWeather';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            data: {},
        };

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        GetWeather.getWeather().then( json => {
            console.log(json);
            this.setState({data: json});

        });
    }
    
    
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
            <Content weather={this.state.data}/>
        );
    }
}

export default App
```

and then in your child component, you should either use one of updating lifecycle methods (that has risks) or you can change your child component to functional component, for you don't need state.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

function Content(props) {

    return (
        <View style={styles.content}>
            <Text style={styles.city}>City Name</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Weather {props.weather.main}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Description</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Temperature Celsius</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Pressure</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Humidity</Text>        
        </View>
     )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    content: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems:'center'
    },
    city: {
        fontSize: 50,
        padding: 20
    },
    itemsize: {
        fontSize: 30,
        padding: 5
    }
})

export default Content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the request finishes you already set `this.state.data` inside `Content` to `null` and it will not get updated when the component re-renders because the constructor only runs once on mount.

Setting `state` from `props` is an anti pattern and should be used only in rare situations.

Instead, read the weather data from `this.props` which will get updated once the parent component updates his state

You would also need to check if `this.props.weather` is `null` before you access `.main` inside `this.props.weather`

```js
class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    const { weather } = this.props

    return (
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text style={styles.city}>City Name</Text>
        <Text style={styles.itemsize}>
          Weather {weather ? weather.main : null}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Description</Text>
        <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Temperature Celsius</Text>
        <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Pressure</Text>
        <Text style={styles.itemsize}>Humidity</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `this.state.data` in the `Home` component is set after the `Content` component is created (after its `constructor` function is called).

This will generate a `TypeError` because `this.props.weather` is `undefined` and you are trying to access a property `this.props.weather.main`.

The easiest way to solve this will be to use the props object directly instead of adding those props to the state, here is an example:

```
<Text style={styles.itemsize}>Weather {this.props.weather}</Text>
```